# Flexbox centering and overflow bug in IE10?

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

[image]

What I want to do basically is have a header and a container always centered if they're small than the screen (body with 100% height). In case the content and header are bigger than the screen, then allow to scroll inside its container (notice that the header shouldn't be scrollable).

I managed to make it work in Chrome but not in IE10. This is the JSFiddle.

```js
var p = $('p');
$('button').click(function(){
 for(var i=0; i<30; i++){
        $('.content').append(p.clone());
    }
});
```

```css
.screen{
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 3px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex; 
    display: -ms-flexbox; 
    justify-content: center; 
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    flex-direction: column; 
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
}

.header{border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px;}
.content{ border: 1px solid green; background: #aaa; overflow: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add more content</button>
<div class="screen">
    <div class="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>This is the content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w8zg8hr2/2/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **`flex: 0 1 auto;`** to the `.content` div and **`overflow: auto;`** to the `.screen` container. IE10 uses the 2012 syntax which defaults to `flex: 0 0 auto` instead of the modern value of `flex: 0 1 auto;`

```js
var p = $('p');
$('button').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        $('.content').append(p.clone());
    }
});
```

```css
.screen {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 3px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
}
.header {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
.content {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: #aaa;
    overflow: auto !important;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Add this property value */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add more content</button>
<div class="screen">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>This is the content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Browserstack screenshot of Win7/IE10:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work in IE10. When I add more content, the content box just grows all the way beyond the screen box instead of allowing scrolling like in Chrome.

Comment: @ErwinGO Are you sure you're testing on IE10 and not some other version or some other document mode? This snippet works in IE10 the same way it works in Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: @ErwinGO I forgot about the container; it needed an overflow property as well... answer has been updated.

Comment: It's close to the solution :) but the header should be always at the top and it doesn't have a fixed height so I can't "position:absolute" it.

Comment: @ErwinGO Ah, I overlooked that part of the question. Yeah, with IE10 and flexbox, that's going to be *really* tricky. Definitely some JavaScript will be necessary to get it to be have properly. However, IE10 has always been evergreen; it should automatically prompt users to update to IE11 ever since IE11 first came out, so hopefully this won't be a problem for many users.